# PHP XPATH: return character in xpath string

Tags: php, string, xpath, count, character

Having trouble finding the first character of Field42 inside xpath, see below. Any suggestions?

```
$letters = split(',','0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z');
foreach($letters AS $letter) {
if(count($item->xpath("/Entries/Entry[Field42{0}='".$letter."']")) > 0) {
        $entries = $item->xpath("/Entries/Entry[Field42{0}='".$letter."']"); ?>
```

**XML Structure**

```
<Entries>
<Entry>
    <EntryId>33</EntryId>
    <Field71/>
    <Field41>Jane</Field41>
    <Field42>Smith</Field42>
```

Comment: You can create the `$letters` array easier with `array_merge(range(0,9), range('a', 'z'))`. What is happening with your code? Any errors? What do you want and what does it do? Are you sure your XPath is valid? I have never seen `{0}` (but that does not mean anything),

Comment: Can you post the structure of one of the Entry records?

Comment: @Felix - nothing's happening, $string{0}=s, but inside of xpath it's not working. Do you know of a way around it? I need to alphabetize my entries.

Comment: @MacAnthony - basic xml structure that needs to be alphabetized by last name.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Well, I bet PHP throws some error or warning, telling you that the XPath expressions is not valid.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Check my answer with an XPath expression only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath's `starts-with` function:

```
$item->xpath("/Entries/Entry[starts-with(Field42,'".$letter."')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all `Entry` elements starting with a letter from a given string, use:

`/Entries/Entry[contains('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',substring(.,1,1))]`